# QProcess output with adb always empty

Tags: qt, adb, qprocess

I am starting a QProcess to get e.g. the return of "adb devices".
There is no error and always an empty response. I have adb in my system env on Windows and the command runs fine on cmd.

Am I doing anythin wrong or is there another way to run adb commands in QT?

```
class ADBInfo: public QObject {
public:
    void start(){
        process = new QProcess( this );
        process->start("adb.exe devices");

        process->waitForFinished(-1);

        qDebug() << "output: " << process->readAll();
        qDebug() << "error: " << process->readAllStandardError();
    }
private:
    QProcess *process;
};
```

Comment: You did not verify that the process actually started.

Comment: I think its not running ... move `devices` to the process _argument list_

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct way

```
   QString mainwindow::cmd(const QString &command)
   {
    qDebug () << "command = "+command;
    QProcess P2;
    P2.start(command);
    P2.waitForFinished(-1);
    P2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    QTextStream reade2(&P2);
    QString line2,line,Out;
    while (reade2.readLineInto(&line2))
        Out.append(line2 +'\n');
    P2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardError);
    QTextStream reader(&P2);
    while (reader.readLineInto(&line))
        Out.append(line +'\n');
    P2.close();
    return Out.trimmed();
}
```

when you need to excute command

```
QString Result = cmd("adb devices")
```